# CoreOS docker host cannot access containers by IP; other computers on LAN can

Tags: linux-networking, docker, local-area-network, coreos

We have a problem that our server hosting our containers are unable to access them with their IP, while other computers on the network can. We've got the following setup for our LAN:

- A server connected to the router by two cables(running CoreOS 1068.10.0 and Docker 1.10.3)
- A router that connects the server and clients
- A number of client computers that are all either directly connected to the router or by a switch connected to the router

So our network looks like this, super simple:

```
    |---------|           |---------|           |---------|
    | Docker  |-----------| Router  |-----------| Other computers/
    | Host    |-----------|         |           | NAS/etc |
    |---------|           |---------|           |---------|
```

In order to expose our containers to our network, we've followed this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35799206

I.e. the commands we've used are these:

```
 docker network create \
  --subnet 192.168.0.0/16 \
  --aux-address "DefaultGatewayIPv4=192.168.0.1" \
  --gateway=192.168.1.1 \
  -o com.docker.network.bridge.name=br-internal_lan internal_lan

 sudo brctl addif br-internal_lan eno1
 sudo ip a del 192.168.1.1/16 dev br-internal_lan
```

So far so good. Our server has IP 192.168.0.3 on `eno3`, which is what we want. `eno1` is connected by a separate cable to the router and is used for the bridge. The bridge gets IP 192.168.0.83. If we then start our container with:

```
docker run --net=internal_lan -d --ip 192.168.1.0 serverimage:latest
```

We get the following scenario:

- Works: ping containers from clients(and vice versa)
- Works: ping host from clients(and vice versa)
- Works: ping bridge IP from containers, host, clients
- Works: ping host from containers
- Works: run `docker exec container01 /bin/bash` to get access to containers
- **DOESN'T WORK: ping containers from host**, packet loss is 100%

These are some sample settings from our server:

ifconfig

```
br-internal_lan: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.0.83  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 192.168.255.255
    inet6 fe80::42:8cff:fe30:3b4a  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether 02:42:8c:30:3b:4a  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 430214  bytes 62591783 (59.6 MiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 4244  bytes 546612 (533.8 KiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eno1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet6 fe80::225:90ff:fe5d:6b80  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether 00:25:90:5d:6b:80  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 829691  bytes 296523943 (282.7 MiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 78684  bytes 87560787 (83.5 MiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
    device memory 0xdf400000-df47ffff

eno3: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.0.3  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 192.168.255.255
    inet6 fe80::225:90ff:fe5d:6b82  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether 00:25:90:5d:6b:82  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 1744808  bytes 1583970565 (1.4 GiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 1019186  bytes 1085667196 (1.0 GiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
    device memory 0xdf200000-df27ffff

<other interfaces omitted>
```

route

```
default         router.asus.com 0.0.0.0         UG    1024   0        0 eno3
default         router.asus.com 0.0.0.0         UG    1024   0        0 br-internal_lan
172.17.0.0      *               255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
192.168.0.0     *               255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 eno3
192.168.0.0     *               255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-internal_lan
router.asus.com *               255.255.255.255 UH    1024   0        0 eno3
router.asus.com *               255.255.255.255 UH    1024   0        0 br-internal_lan
```

We've tried changing `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/[eno1,eno3,br-internal_lan]/rp_filter` to 2, but it didn't change anything(don't know if it should). `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` is set to 1.

What could be wrong with our setup? How can we get access by IP to our containers? Any help is appreciated, if I need to supply additional information please let us know.

(Note that we are currently running Docker 1.10.3(which is the latest Docker release when using CoreOS stable), so macvlan is not an option for us.)